# How to create a companion file using WiX's Heat tool

Tags: wix, heat

Our build process pulls in .dll's and creates 'policy.*.dll' files and the companion 'policy.*.config' files from them.  While looking through WiX's 'dark' output of our MSI, I discovered that the policy and corresponding config files were within the same Component linked by the CompanionFile tag.

Is there a way to have Heat harvest the 'policy.*.dll' Files and companion 'policy.*.config' Files within the same Component tag at the same time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to write an XSLT to transform the output to combine the two files in one `Component` and mark the `CompanionFile` attribute on one of the `File` elements. XSLT is basically the ultimate general purpose transformation for all heat output (even if XSL is kinda' complex).

Comment: I thought XSLT may be the way to do it but I didn't want to take on the additional undertaking of learning another complex language on top of WiX if there may have been an easy solution I had overlooked.  Thanks @RobMensching!